# Retag androidhttpclient to android-httpclient?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I was adding tags to a question the other day since the only tag was [android](/questions/tagged/android). I skimmed through the question and saw that they were asking about http client in android so I went to tag the question as such and noticed that there was no `android-httpclient` tag, but instead there was [androidhttpclient](/questions/tagged/androidhttpclient). Should [androidhttpclient](/questions/tagged/androidhttpclient) be retagged as `android-httpclient` to follow the format that all other android-specific tags use? (Also I do not have enough rep to do such so someone else would need to do this)